# iptables: config not NATting properly

Tags: iptables, nat

```
#port 35001 -> x.x.x.247 (34197)
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d x.x.x.247 --dport 34197 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.246:35001
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -s localhost --sport 35001 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.247:34197
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -s x.x.x.246 --sport 35001 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.247:34197


#port 35000 -> x.x.x.246 (34197)
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d x.x.x.246 --dport 34197 -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.246:35000
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -s localhost --sport 35000 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.246:34197
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -s x.x.x.246 --sport 35000 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.246:34197
```

When I try to use this configuration, it is still possible to (for example) receive packets on a remote host that indicate they came from port 35001 on the server. How can I translate packets so that all packets originating from port 35001 are translated to the new IP and port?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question: I needed to use -j REDIRECT instead of -j DNAT